# Solving an equation in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

Could you please help me to solve the following equation in $\mathbb{C}$:

$$z^2-2i(1+i)z-1=0$$

This is what I found as discriminent: -8i+4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, now find a square root for that complex number and use the quadratic formula.

Comment: This is a quadratic equation and can be solved as such. There is little difference with this equation over the reals.

Comment: This is my problem I don't know how to do that.

Comment: What is "that"? You don't know how to find a complex square root? Whoever assigned you that problem should have taught you how to find the square roots of a complex number.

Comment: Unless it is required to give the answer in real and imaginary parts, then it should be OK if your answer has the $\sqrt{\;}$ sign in it.

Answer (score 0):

I take it then that the problem is calculating $\sqrt{4- 8i}$.

The simplest way to take the square root of a complex number is to convert to "polar form".  The absolute value of $4- 8i$ is $\sqrt{16+ 64}= \sqrt{80}= \sqrt{16(5)}= 4\sqrt{5}$ and the argument is $\arctan(-8/4)= \arctan(-2)$.   The square root of that has absolute value $2\sqrt[4]{5}$ and argument $\dfrac{\arctan(-2)}{2}$